# Master detail plot with hvplot, Holoviews and Bokeh in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews, hvplot

I have a dataset (Pandas DataFrame) that I'm plotting in a Bokeh scatter plot by means of `hvplot`. For each and every datapoint in that master dataset (also DataFrame) there is an additional dataset available with more detailed data.

I would like to plot that additional detail dataset in a separate plot each time a datapoint is selected in the master plot.

All of that is to be done in Jupyter Lab.

Is that possible, if it is, how would I go on about it? Will it need utilization of hooks?

Comment: Here's an example that uses HoloViews Tap and streams: http://holoviews.org/reference/streams/bokeh/heatmap_tap.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, @SandervandenOord. That's close to what I'm looking for. One thing though is that I'm using `hvplot` to generate the `hv.Scatter` plot and I don't see yet how to do the `dataset.select` part of the example with that. Do you know by any chance how to go on about that?

Comment: You can also try asking your question on https://discourse.holoviz.org/ but I do think you have to be a bit more specific on your question and add sample data and code.

Comment: Okay, I'll come up with some example code and data tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Alright, "tomorrow" turned into "after my vacation"... sorry...